# Does UIGestureRecognizer know what object it is called on?

Tags: ios, dynamic, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIGestureRecognizer that I want to work on two different UIViews, both of which are in the same view hierarchy of a UiViewController.  The action of the UIGestureRecognizer is about the same on each, so I would like for the same function to be called (it will, obviously) and I will tell at runtime which of the UIViews I am dealing with.  But how?  I cannot see that the UIGestureRecognizer is carrying the object information with it.  Am I missing the line in the documentation or does the gestureRecognizer not know which object that it has been attached to that it is being called on?  Seems like the point of the language would be that it would know.

Alternatively, maybe I am misunderstanding the intent of the class and I should not:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *dblTap = 
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self 
                                        action: @selector(handleDblTap:)];   
[viewA addGestureRecognizer: dblTap]; 
[viewB addGestureRecognizer: dblTap];
```

and then expect to be able to:

```
-(void)handleDblTap: (UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
     if (viewA)...
```

If in fact UIGestureRecognizer does not support being attached to multiple objects simultaneously, then, if you know why it does not support this, could you educate me? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NJones is right. One view per recognizer. You can also set a tag for each recognizer to find out which recognizer called that method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The standard is one view per recognizer. But you can still efficiently use one handler method.

You would instantiate the recognizers like so:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *dblTapViewA = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDblTap:)];   
[viewA addGestureRecognizer: dblTapViewA]; 

UITapGestureRecognizer *dblTapViewB = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDblTap:)];
[viewB addGestureRecognizer: dblTapViewB];
```

Then your handler method could look something like:

```
-(void)handleDblTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRec{
    if (tapRec.view == viewA){
        // double tap view a
    } else if (tapRec.view == viewB) {
        // double tap view b
    }
}
```

Comment: That was well explained for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a Tag to view and then simply compare that tag and perform action.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *dblTap = 
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self 
                                    action: @selector(handleDblTap:)];   
[view addGestureRecognizer: dblTap];
view.tag = 2000; // set any integer
```

And while calling

```
-(void)handleDblTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRec{
    if (tapRec.view.tag == 2000){
      // double tap view with tag
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *dblTapA = 
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self 
                                    action: @selector(handleDblTap:)];   
[viewA addGestureRecognizer: dblTapA]; 

UITapGestureRecognizer *dblTapB = 
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self 
                                    action: @selector(handleDblTap:)];   
[viewA addGestureRecognizer: dblTapB];
```